# Changing the type of an input element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `input type="text"` that I want converted to an `input type="button"`. I have tried `attr()`, but that [does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/DsnSn/):

HTML:

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input').attr('type', 'button');
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I fixed your title for you. Please write meaningful titles in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the `type` attribute with jQuery. This is from the jQuery [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L392):

```
// We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)
if ( rtype.test( elem.nodeName ) && elem.parentNode ) {
    jQuery.error( "type property can't be changed" );
}
```

The reason, according to the comment, is that it causes problems in IE. Since jQuery is designed to reduce complications that arise due to differences between browsers, it would go against that idea if it worked in other browsers. I'm assuming that's why the jQuery team have simply removed that ability.

As has already been mentioned, your best option will probably be to replace the `input` element in question with a new one.

Comment: Thanks! How do I catch these kind of errors thrown in the futur?

Comment: @Randomblue - You can use a `try...catch` block to catch any exceptions that occur within the `try` part. Aside from that, you can tell when an exception is thrown as it will appear in the console (in Chrome at least, haven't tried it in other browsers).

Answer (score 0):

This is partially covered in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> **Note:** Internet Explorer does not allow you to change the type
>   attribute of an `<input>` or `<button>` element.

That you are prevented from even attempting this in any browser comes from the jQuery source:

```
// We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)
if ( name == "type" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "input" ) && elem.parentNode )
    throw "type property can't be changed";
```

(Looks like the docs need updating.)